# Does a thread exit out of every synchronized method or object upon blocking?

Tags: java, multithreading

If I have something like this

```
synchronized void doSomething() throws Exception {
    synchronized (lock1) {
        lock1.wait();
    }
    wait();
}
```

Once it blocks at `lock1.wait()`,  will some other thread be able to access `doSomething()` and do work in it?

What if the blocked thread gets signaled and regains entry to the method? will it block on `wait()` or not?

Comment: Mind that this will not take into consideration that spurious wakeups can happen. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait--

Answer (score 1):

No, calling `wait()` releases the lock on the object that you're calling `wait()` on only. In the example code the lock on `lock1` will be released, but the lock on `this` is still kept by the thread.